# Could not find Control in ControlParameter inside EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, linq-to-entities, dynamic-data

I am working on a Dynamic Data website and I have run into a wall. I have a Details page where the details for each employee can be seen, and then I have a separate page to edit each employee. I did this because I need to use DropDownList boxes for Department and Job in each department. Nevertheless, I am having trouble accessing the department ddl and I think it is because it is inside an EditItemTemplate. Here is what I have:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvEmployee" 
                    DataSourceID="EmpDVds" 
                    AutoGenerateRows="false" 
                    DataKeyNames="Id" 
                    GridLines="None" 
                    CellSpacing="10" 
                    runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderText="Department: ">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDept" DataSourceID="DeptDDLds" DataTextField = "DepartmentName" DataValueField = "Id" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("DeptID") %>' />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderText="Job Code: ">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJob" DataSourceID="JobDDLds" DataTextField = "JobName" DataValueField = "Id" runat="server" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Fields>
```

Then I am trying to use the ddlDept SelectedValue to populate the ddlJob. Here is the DataSource I am trying to use.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="JobDDLds"
                    SelectCommand="
                        SELECT 
                        Id, 
                        Code+' - '+[Desc] AS JobName,
                        Department_Id 
                        FROM 
                        JobCodes 
                        WHERE
                        JobCodes.Department_Id = @DeptID"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:TrainingDatabaseConnection %>" runat="server" >
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDept" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                    Name="DeptID" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I know that the format of the Select parameter is correct because I am using another ddl to populate the DetailsView and I know the relationship between Departments and JobCodes is correct because I am using it successfully in and AddEmployee page.

Here is the error I get:

Could not find control 'ddlDept' in ControlParameter 'DeptID'.

I am I correct in assuming that it cannot access the ddlDept by it's ID because it is in the EditItemTemplate? How can I fix this? Other suggestions on how to achieve this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2006/08/27/89475.aspx) helps. Is not an ideal solution, but it might works for you.

Answer (score 19):

I found this link helps to solve without server side: [Solving the error "Could not find control 'xxx' in ControlParameter 'xxx'."](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2006/08/27/89475.aspx)

the author says that you can use the dollar char (**$**) to access the inner control.

Ex:

`ControlID="dvEmployee$ddlDept"`

will get the value of ddlDept that is a inner control of dvEmployee

Comment: This is a great solution. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: This only works if the DOM can see it. Otherwise, it's the same problem

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is correct; the `<ControlParameter`> doesn't recognize your ddlDept because it's in a different `ContentTemplate`.

One way to work around this is to remove the `<ControlParameter>` from your markup and add it programatically at runtime, so that you can use ddlDept's actual `UniqueID` property.

Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Create your ControlParameter
        ControlParameter deptParam = new ControlParameter();
        deptParam.ControlID = ddlDept.UniqueID;
        deptParam.PropertyName = "SelectedValue";
        deptParam.Name = "DeptID";
        deptParam.Type = TypeCode.Int32;
        // Add it to your SelectParameters collection
        JobDDLds.SelectParameters.Add(deptParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have access to server-side code, this falls down. How would one go about this client-side?

Comment: Hey, @CodeMaverick - the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653516/861565) on this question has a good solution that I know works if you have access to the markup.  If you mean client-side as in JavaScript, you may have to be a bit more creative.  The server generated ID for the dropdown lists will contain the server side ID, so you could use the ["attribute contains selector"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to get all of the dropdowns, and then iterate through them, setting the correct selected value based on context (sibling controls, etc).

Answer (score 3):

One way I've found to get around this issue with data source objects looking for controls inside the context of a DetailsView or GridView control is to actually place the data source control inside the item/edit item template that has the controls you wish to reference. This might not be ideal for all situations, but it certainly works.

Comment: Worked best in my situation: A DetailsView(dv) with a DropDownList(ddl) that is bound to a second datasource(s2) that requires ddl.SelectedValue as a select-parameter. If s2 was placed outside of dv and dv is NOT visible (happens in my code), s2 would still try to access ddl and strange things happen.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is, set your dropdownlist client id mode to be static. Then your dropdownlist id will not be modified.

```
 ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Thanks,

Esen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your control of interest has runat="server".  Argh.

Answer (score 0):

if you talking about gridview (add new record button)
 use

```
    <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String"/>
```

instead of

```
    <asp:ControlParameter    Name="Type"    ControlID="rddType"   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
```